# Developing a Java program using the Spring-Boot framework, the problem of character encoding

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, encoding, web-applications

My task is to write a program in Java using the Spring Boot framework. Below is the code I wrote for this application. The problem is that when I pull text from textarea, special characters and Russian letters are not correctly passed to the variable, and when the message variable is output to the console, the wrong text is obtained that the user entered.

How can I make sure that there is no such error?

[Entering text on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXpSN.png)
Output:
`Сообщение получено: File received and decrypted: message=Hello+World%3B+%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%3B+1234567890%3B+%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26*%28%29-%2B_%3D%2F%5C%3C%3E%2C.%7E%3B`

I tried to change the encodings on the website and in the code.

Below is the code of the site and the client application:

```java
package com.mvas.client.controller;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class ClientController {

    private RSAPublicKey clientPublicKey;
    private RSAPrivateKey clientPrivateKey;
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String toIndex(){
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/sendMessage")
    public String sendMessage(@RequestBody String message, Model model) {
        try {
            System.out.println(message);
            List<String> encryptedBlocks = encryptWithServerPublicKey(message);
            System.out.println(encryptedBlocks);
            String response = sendEncryptedBlocksToServer(encryptedBlocks);
            model.addAttribute("response", "Сообщение получено: " + response);
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            model.addAttribute("response", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return "result";
    }

    private List<String> encryptWithServerPublicKey(String message) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8081/getServerPublicKey";
        String serverPublicKeyBase64 = restTemplate.postForObject(serverUrl, null, String.class);
        RSAPublicKey serverPublicKey = decodeRSAPublicKey(serverPublicKeyBase64);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING", "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, serverPublicKey);
        System.out.println(cipher);
        byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int inputLen = messageBytes.length;
        int blockSize = 245;
        List<String> encryptedBlocks = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < inputLen; i += blockSize) {
            int currentBlockSize = Math.min(blockSize, inputLen - i);
            byte[] block = cipher.doFinal(messageBytes, i, currentBlockSize);
            encryptedBlocks.add(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(block));
        }

        return encryptedBlocks;
    }

    private RSAPublicKey decodeRSAPublicKey(String publicKeyBase64) throws Exception {
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyBase64);
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
        return (RSAPublicKey) KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(keySpec);
    }

    private String sendEncryptedBlocksToServer(List<String> encryptedBlocks) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<List<String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(encryptedBlocks, headers);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8081/receiveFile";
        return restTemplate.postForObject(serverUrl, request, String.class);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Input Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Введите сообщение</h1>
<form action="/sendMessage" method="post">
    <textarea type="text" name="message" placeholder="Ваше сообщение" required></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you did wrong but your output is URL encoded so you need URL decoder for that